# Using functions with completion handlers firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm trying to fetch some images from my firebase storage, and append it to the empty FBPicArray variable.

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
let imageNames = ["firstImage.jpg", "seccondImage.jpg", "thirdImage.jpg"]
var FBPicArray = [UIImage]()


func loadFirebaseIMG(resultPicArray: @escaping([UIImage]) -> ()) {

       for item in imageNames {
    let storageref = storage.reference(withPath: "Images/\(item)")
    storageref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("FB storage error:", error)
        } else {
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.FBPicArray.append(image!)
            resultPicArray(self.FBPicArray)
        }
        }
    }
}
```

So dar so good. I'm able to access the FBPicArray when calling the function, however I run into problems when I want to do things like display the amount of cells as there are images in the array:

```
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    loadFirebaseIMG { (img) in

    }

    return FBPicArray.count
}
```

Running the function here leaves me with no cells displaying when i do like the example above, however when i try to put the return statement inside the loadFirebaseIMG function this does not work either. How can i access this data outside of my function to use elsewhere in my code?

Comment: start var names with small letter `fBPicArray `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any completions instead change to

```
func loadFirebaseIMG() {

   for item in imageNames {
    let storageref = storage.reference(withPath: "Images/\(item)")
    storageref.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { (data, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("FB storage error:", error)
        } else {
            let image = UIImage(data: data!)
            self.fBPicArray.append(image!) 
            self.collectionView.reloadData() // reload the collection when you receive an image , performance tip is to use insertItems
        }
        }
    }
} 
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {  
    return fBPicArray.count
}
```

and call `loadFirebaseIMG` inside `viewDidLoad` , if you need to load them all then refresh the collection finally which i don't recommend then go with `DispatchGroup`